# Как менять местами элементы списка?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

Как последний элемент списка поменять местами с заданным по индексу элементом того же списка?

```
n = int(input('Введите количество k элементов списка: '))
print('Введите содержимое каждого из k подсписков своими руками через пробел.')
A = []
for i in range(1, n+1):
    arr = list(map(int, input('Для перехода между подсписками k нажимайте Enter: ').split()))
    arr[-1], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[-1]
    A.append(arr)
print(A)
```

Comment: Какое отношение имеет i к реальному размеру введённого подсписка?

Answer (score 12):

Так же, как любые переменные

```
l[-1], l[k] = l[k], l[-1]
```

По `l[-1]` - нужно познакомиться со списками и срезами (slice) - так проще всего обратиться к последнему элементу

По обмену - формируется исходный кортеж (tuple) из значений элементов, потом из этих элементов в обратном порядка образуется новый кортеж,  значения присваиваются новому кортежу.

Comment: А как более понятно это объяснить?

Comment: @Петрович Например есть список `l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` . Мы хотим поменять местами первый и последний элементы списка. Пусть `k` - это индекс элемента списка. `k = 0`, индекс первого єдемента списка. Последний элемент имеет ииндекс `-1`. Выполняем `l[-1], l[k] = l[k], l[-1]` . Теперь выводим список на печать `print(l)` . Получаем `[7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1]`

Comment: Ошибка, как исправить? /data/user/0/org.qpython.qpy3/files/bin/qpython-android5.sh "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/.last_tmp.py" && exit
python/.last_tmp.py" && exit             <
Введите количество подсписков в списке 3
введите список 123
введите список 34
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/.last_tmp.py", line 5, in <module>
    arr[-1], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[-1]
IndexError: list index out of range
1|mido:/ $

Comment: k = int(input('Введите количество подсписков в списке '))
m = []
for i in range(0, k+1):
    arr = list(input('введите список ').split())
    arr[-1], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[-1]
    m.append(arr)
print(m)

Comment: Список пустой или слишком короткий. Потренируйтесь на `m = [1,2,3,4,5]`, чтобы убедиться, что обмен работает. Ввод списка - это уже другая задача. Код в комментариях нечитабелен.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте проанализировать следующий пример:

```
arr = list(map(int, input('Введите некоторое количество целых чисел через пробел: ').split()))
# Например: Введите некоторое количество целых чисел через пробел: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
print(arr)  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

k = -1 # индекс последнего элемента списка при первой итерации

for i in range(len(arr)//2):
    print("\nбыло - ", i, arr)
    arr[k], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[k]
    print("стало    ", arr)
    k -= 1

"""
было -  0 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
стало     [7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1]

было -  1 [7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1]
стало     [7, 6, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1]

было -  2 [7, 6, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1]
стало     [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
"""
```